# Given a text and a pattern that can contain '*' wildcards. Are there algorithms that can match in O(n) time?

Tags: algorithm, pattern-matching

The match should cover the entire text.

For simplicity the text is alphanumeric.

The pattern does not support escapes and accepts only the following wildcard:

'*' - Matches any sequence of characters (also empty)

I have explored  naive implementations like the one below. I have also gone through [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_wildcards), but I have failed to find a definitive  answer to whether it's possible to implement a linear solution.

In the absence of a linear solution, the best alternatives are welcome.

Thanks.

```
bool strmatch(char txt[], char pat[], 
              int n, int m) 
{ 
    if (m == 0) 
        return (n == 0); 

    int i = 0, j = 0, index_txt = -1, 
        index_pat = -1; 

    while (i < n) { 
        if (j < m && txt[i] == pat[j]) { 
            i++; 
            j++; 
        } 
        else if (j < m && pat[j] == '*') { 
            index_txt = i; 
            index_pat = j; 
            j++; 
        } 
        else if (index_pat != -1) { 
            j = index_pat + 1; 
            i = index_txt + 1; 
            index_txt++; 
        } 
        else { 
            return false; 
        } 
    } 
    while (j < m && pat[j] == '*') { 
        j++; 
    } 
    if (j == m) { 
        return true; 
    } 

    return false; 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is an algorithm.

Your pattern is a list of strings, separated by '*'.  The algorithm goes like this:

1. Match the first pattern string against the beginning of the text.
2. Search for all the other pattern strings in the text, starting at the end of the previous match. String search can be implemented in linear time, e.g. using [this algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm).
3. Match the last pattern string against the end of the text.

The complexity of this algorithm is O(n+m), with n as the text size, and m the pattern size.  An implementation in Python would look like this:

```py
def matchpattern(txt, pattern):
  if len(pattern) == 0:
    return len(txt) == 0;
  strings = pattern.split('*')
  if len(strings) == 1: # no star found
    return txt == pattern
  # match the fist piece
  if not txt.startswith(strings[0]):
    return False;      
  # match all except the last substring
  pos = len(strings[0])
  for s in strings[1:-1]:
    pos = txt.find(s, pos)
    if (pos == -1):
      return False
    pos = pos + len(s)

  return len(txt) >= pos + len(strings[-1]) and txt.endswith(strings[-1])

def test(txt, pattern):
  print(repr(txt), repr(pattern), matchpattern(txt, pattern))

test('one', 'one')
test('x one', 'one')
test('one', '*')
test('one', '*one')
test('x one', '*one')
test('one x', 'one')
test('one x', 'one*')
test('one x two', 'one*two')    
test('one one', 'one*one*one')
```

Output:

```
'one' 'one' True
'x one' 'one' False
'one' '*' True
'one' '*one' True
'x one' '*one' True
'one x' 'one' False
'one x' 'one*' True
'one x two' 'one*two' True
'one one' 'one*one*one' False
```

Comment: Yes this is the conclusion that I reached as well.

Answer (score 1):

I think have a list of strings separated by "*" characters. The text must start with the first string in the list, and end with the last string in the list. All of the other strings must occur somewhere in the rest of the text, in sequence. Checking the presence of the first and last string is easy. Between these two, I think you can search for the other strings one at a time with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm (Knuth-Morris-Pratt) in linear time, searching for each string after you have found the previous string.

Comment: I think that this is definitely a possible solution. However, by looking for first and last substrings match the worst case won't be linear.
I would rather search the substrings in order of appearance in the pattern, at every match we move to the next substring and discard the already seen part of the text.